# Find a word in Range and Find it again until the end of Range

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I need to `Find` a word in `Range("A1:A7500")` then `Find` it again until the end of the `Range` (just like MSword VBA). Whenever word is found I need to do something with it or you can say count the occurrence.

But problem is, the `Range` will change when text is found. So how can I reset my range from next row where the text is found to the end? or is there any-other way to have the same result?

```
    Dim FIN,FOUN As Range
    Set FIN = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A7500")
    Do
    Set FOUN = FIN.find("TEXT", LookIn:=xlValues)

     ' IF FOUND THEN DO SOMETHING HERE

    Loop
```

Comment: You can set A:A as range so it will select the whole column and you won't have problems with it changing

Comment: Btw if you need to count the occurrence of a word in a column, there are easyest ways to do such a thing

Comment: Ok, but you can still try to make the range as A:A instead of A:A7500

Comment: Brother take a look, I have change your code according to my situation and updated my question. facing little problem can you help?

Comment: @IbneAshiq Please don't change your question after you got answers. You can ask another question and reference this one instead. Chabging the question invalidates the answers. I rolled back to the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FindAndChange()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")   ' <- change the worksheet to point to your sheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long: iLastRow = oWS.Range("A" & oWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim oRng As Range: Set oRng = oWS.Range("A1:A" & iLastRow)          ' <- change the column name if its not column A
    Dim oFoundRng As Range, oLastRng As Range
    Dim sTextToFind As String: sTextToFind = "test"

    ' Find the first instance of the text to find
    Set oFoundRng = oRng.Find(sTextToFind)

    ' Loop to find all instances of the text
    Do While Not oFoundRng Is Nothing

        oFoundRng.Value = "Found test"              ' Change the text to whatever it is you want to here
        Set oLastRng = oFoundRng                    ' Assign the current range to last range so that we dont go into an endless loop
        Set oFoundRng = oRng.FindNext(oFoundRng)    ' Find the next instance of the text
        If oLastRng >= oFoundRng Then               ' Ensure we dont start from the top again
            Exit Do                                 ' We are back at the top so exit loop
        End If
    Loop

    ' Clear objects
    Set oFoundRng = Nothing
    Set oWS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It's basically there just incase when you change your text, the new text doesn't contain the text you are looking for. Otherwise you will get into an endless loop. Try it.. in column `A`, have a few rows with text and set 2 or more cells with the text **test**. then run the above UDF. What you will find is that once the text is changed to **Found test**, `FindNext` will then find the first instance of the cell where text is **Found test**. This is just to cover that scenario

Comment: I think line If oLastRng >= oFoundRng Then exiting do before finding next. actually its finding only once. and exiting even if "Found test" exist 2 time in range

Comment: It depends on what you changing your text to. I would suggest to leave that in there just incase you get into an endless loop

Answer (score 1):

I would accomplish this with a generic FindAll function.

For Example:

```
Sub FindTest()
    Dim r As Range, Cell As Range
    Set r = FindAll("Test", Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A7500"), LookAt:=xlPart)

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print r.Count
        For Each Cell In r
            Cell.value = "Test2"
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub

Private Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat, _
    Optional IncludeMerged As Boolean = False) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-""" _
     Set IncludeMerged to 'True' to include all cells within a merged area

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = IIf(IncludeMerged = True, CurrRange.MergeArea, CurrRange)
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, IIf(IncludeMerged = True, CurrRange.MergeArea, CurrRange))
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```